# size/coordinates of wrapped text object in tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

How do I get coordinates of a wrapped text object in Tkinter Canvas?

I know I can use `canvas.bbox(text_object)` but it will give me only box coordinates.
But if the text is wrapped I need to get coordinates of last char in the last line.

I want to put a polygon under text so as to make background color for text only.

I got this using  `canvas.bbox(text_object)`
[image]

I want it to be like this :
[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand why the box coordinates are not right for what you want to do. Could you provide a minimal example with some wrapped text in the canvas?

Comment: I just attached some example. I want to create a red background under text only using polygon. I guess I would need coordintaes of the last word in my string.

Comment: You could use a frame with a label, then use `create_window` to achieve that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want a rectangular background but a polygon that will stop at the end of the last word (i.e. remove the red part with no text on it)?

Comment: Yes  ,   i .e. remove the red part with no text on it

Comment: Will you only ever need to do this for one piece of text? If so, you can use the selection mechanism to select the text, and then set `selectbackground` to red.

Comment: I will have several texts on my canvas. The text can be more more than one line. I'm also trying to avoid using widgets. I need just to get constant background.

Comment: Those texts objects will be of different colors so i can not just asign  highlightbackground to canvas

Comment: This would be trivial with a text widget. Do you have a hard requirement to use a canvas?

Comment: I need to use a canvas for this project . The text will be of 2 parts: lable name and  sentence.  My idea was to concatenate  'lable_name' +  'sentence'  and  create one text with borders (outline).Then I just need to figure out shape/coordinates of label_name and put some background rectangle or polygon under it. But what if the label_name is too long and must be wrapped...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x+1, y+1)` to find the boundaries of your text:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_bg(item, bg='red'):
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(item)
    # start of last line
    x = x0
    y = y1 - 1
    # find end x of last line
    while x < x1 and item in canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x + 1, y + 1):
        x += 1
    # find top y of last line
    while y > y0 and item not in canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x + 1, y + 1):
        y -= 1
    y += 1
    vertices = [x0, y0, x1, y0, x1, y, x, y, x, y1, x0, y1]
    bg = canvas.create_polygon(*vertices, fill=bg)
    canvas.tag_lower(bg, item)


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

item = canvas.create_text(20, 20, anchor='nw', width=150,
                          text='This is an example of wrapped text.')


item2 = canvas.create_text(20, 120, anchor='nw', font='Arial 20', width=150,
                           text='This is an example of wrapped text.')

create_bg(item)
create_bg(item2, 'cyan')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your help, surely it will work. Though I expected more simple solution.

Comment: @DV I agree, this should be more simple. The canvas obviously knows exactly the space occupied by the text since `find_overlapping()` does not use the bounding box but the actual text. Though I have no idea how to access this information about the item.