# How to change the color of a single word in the middle of a text object in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have text with multiple lines in a canvas and I would like to change the color of a single word, but I am not able to change it with insert(), is there a way of doing it? Also, how do I find the position of the last word on a create_text() object with many lines?

```
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

fn = "Helvetica"
fs = 24
font = font.Font(family=fn, size=fs)
    
word1 = "I would like the last word of this phrase to be another color, maybe "
word2 = "red"
word3 = "... some other text that should be black again"

t1 = c.create_text(50,50,text=word1, anchor='nw', font=font, width=600)

#I would like this next word to be another color (red, green...)
c.insert(t1, "end", word2)

#then I would like it to be black again
c.insert(t1, "end", word3)

root.geometry('800x500+200+200')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello? Did you test my code?

Comment: Yes, it worked, but you deleted it before I could accept :/

Comment: The canvas widget isn't particularly well suited for this. Is there a reason you're using a canvas to display colored text rather than a text widget?

Comment: Nothing personal really, I found a decent solution here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247399/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this code;

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

fn = "Helvetica"
fs = 24
font = font.Font(family=fn, size=fs)

sentence = '''
I would like the last word of this phrase to be another color, maybe red ... some other text that should be black again
'''

def change_color(sentence, color, start_p, end_p):
    sentence = sentence.rstrip()
    t1 = c.create_text(50, 50, text=sentence, anchor='nw', font=font, width=600)
    t2 = c.create_text(50, 50, text=sentence[:end_p], anchor='nw', font=font, width=600, fill=color)
    t3 = c.create_text(50, 50, text=sentence[:start_p], anchor='nw', font=font, width=600)


change_color(sentence=sentence, color="red", start_p=70, end_p=73)
root.geometry('800x500+200+200')
root.mainloop()
```

start_p is a start position and end_p  is an end position of a substring to change color.

Comment: It works for that particular example, but what if the world was in the middle of the phrase? I edited the question with that other case.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAYBE Using ANSI ESCAPE CODE

class ANSI():
    def background(code):
        return "\33[{code}m".format(code=code)
    def style_text(code):
        return "\33[{code}m".format(code=code)
    def color_text(code):
        return "\33[{code}m".format(code=code)
  
def ANSISET(background,color,style,words) :
    return ANSI.background(background) + ANSI.color_text(color) + ANSI.style_text(style) + " " + words

    sentence ="I would like the last word of this phrase to be another 
color, maybe {} ... some other text that should be black again".format(ANSI(49,31,1,"red"))

#Default Foreground Color Code=39 AND Background Color Code=49 (RESET=0)
Note: the Reset color is the reset code that resets all colors and text effects, Use Default color to reset colors only

 #background: allows background formatting. Accepts ANSI codes between 40 and 47, 100 and 107
 #style_text: corresponds to formatting the style of the text. Accepts ANSI code between 0 and 8
 #color_text:  Corresponds to the text of the color. Accepts ANSI code between 30 and 37, 90 and 97
```